# map-box compass listener on Android

Tags: android, mapbox

is it possible to register when the compass is clicked in map-box?, I saw a `MapboxMap.OnCompassAnimationListener` that it is an interface but when i implemented it didn't work (Android)
thanks

Comment: There is no exposed click listener for compass at this point. You can open a ticket [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues).

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the click (I use com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.13.0):

```
CompassView compassView = findViewById(R.id.compassView);
compassView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Compass clicked");
    }
});
```

But after this you have to do the overridden onClick logic on your own.

Comment: i thought that but i couldn't find the compassView, i ended up creating my own compass button and so far it seems to work just fine, thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

The best way to "check" the click, is using touch listener, if you override the onClickListener the functionality in the compass will not work (animation and so on)
I found the way to do it. (you can add extra step event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)

```
 mapView.findViewWithTag<View>("compassView")?.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
                Toast.makeText(context, "touch listener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                false
            }
```

this will work but if you update mapbox, make sure that the `compassView` does not change

Answer (score 0):

Non of the above solutions worked for me.
My mapbox version is 8.2.2.

This worked for me :

```
var onCompassAnimationFinishedLastCallTimeStamp = 0L
var GUARD_MILLIS = 3000L
private fun registerCompassOnClickListener() {
    val id = resources.getIdentifier("compassView", "id", requireContext().packageName)
    if (id != 0) {
        val compassView:CompassView = mapView.findViewById(id)
        compassView.injectCompassAnimationListener(object :MapboxMap.OnCompassAnimationListener{
            override fun onCompassAnimation() {

            }

            override fun onCompassAnimationFinished() {
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - onCompassAnimationFinishedLastCallTimeStamp > GUARD_MILLIS)   {
                    onCompassAnimationFinishedLastCallTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    Log.d("compass:::", "compass clicked")
                    MapAnalyticsCollector.onCompassPressed()
                }
            }

        })
    }
}
```

Important notes :

- I think that this can also be solved if you provided your own compassView but haven't tried it .
- resources.getIdentifier is an expensive operation .
- this implementation is kind of static because it is using constant name "compassView" which will likely change in future releases , so if you upgrade mapbox version check if they exposed a proper listener for this , if not then at least make sure to update the name "compassView" if needed .
- Due to an issue in mapbox 8.2.2 this listener keeps getting called so I added a time guard to filter the extra calls .